# Site, ignoring attribute. Could someone please explain this action

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been given the horrible task of fixing a website that was created by someone else. I've almost comepleted it but I've hit a stumbling block.

Essentially, I have a homepage which should display 6 events in a 2 row, column layout. The event should only appear on the homepage if the **HOMEPAGE** attribute is added when creating a post. However, every post is now adding to the homepage, whether the HOMEPAGE attribute is added or not.

This is the action that is on the homepage at the minute. My PHP knowledge is limited, so could someone please explain what it's asked to do. Why is it suddenly ignoring the HOMEPAGE attribute?

```
<?php if(is_front_page()): ?>
        <div id="eventBoxes">
            <ul>
            <?php $vReturn = eme_get_events_list('limit=6'); ?> 

            <?php 

                $vReturn = explode("</li>",$vReturn);

                foreach($vReturn as $item) {
                    if(strpos($item,'<div id="homepage">yes</div>') !== false) {
                        echo $item;
                    }
                }

            ?>

            </ul>
            <br class="clear" />


    <?php else: ?>
        <div id="content">

        <?php echo the_content(); ?>

        </div>          

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here's a link to the HTML that this action outputs; http://pastebin.com/Benmr0pd

Comment: I would say the *"horrible task"* is more accurately defined as being asked to wade through the wordpress spaghetti code ;)

Comment: Is it possible that the `eme_get_events_list()` function is adding your homepage attribute to the item based on some other criterion?

Comment: Where is the code for is_front_page() function?

Comment: I can't find where the function is. It's so annoying. I've tried searching 'Homepage' in all the plugin files to see if I can see whee it's referenced, but nothing's showed up. Similarly, nothing's showing up when I search for the other attributes, and they do work.

Answer (score 1):

First, as requested, I'll break down what this code does for you:

```
<?php if (is_front_page()): ?>
  <!-- everything between the line above and <?ph p else: ?> is exectuted if it is the home page -->
    <div id="eventBoxes">
        <ul>
        <!-- this line populates the variable $vReturn with the result of the function eme_get_events_list() -->
        <?php $vReturn = eme_get_events_list('limit=6'); ?> 

        <?php 


            // split the string into an array, based on the <li> tags
            $vReturn = explode("</li>",$vReturn);

            foreach($vReturn as $item) {
                // loop the items
                if(strpos($item,'<div id="homepage">yes</div>') !== false) {
                    // display the item if it contains the string <div id="homepage">yes</div>
                    echo $item;
                }
            }

        ?>

        </ul>
        <br class="clear" />


<?php else: ?>

   <!-- stuff here is for when you're not on the home page -->
    <div id="content">

    <?php echo the_content(); ?>

    </div>          

<?php endif; ?>
```

Next, some observations:

- Your code is case sensitive. This may be the source of the problem.
- Your code will produce broken HTML

Try this on for size:

```
<?php if (is_front_page()): ?>
    <div id="eventBoxes">
        <ul>
<?php

  $vReturn = preg_split("#</li>#i", eme_get_events_list('limit=6'), 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

  foreach($vReturn as $item) {
    if (stripos($item,'<div id="homepage">yes</div>') !== false) {
      echo $item.'</li>';
    }
  }

?>

        </ul>
        <!-- you are almost certainly missing a </div> here -->
        <br class="clear" />


<?php else: ?>

   <!-- stuff here is for when you're not on the home page -->
    <div id="content">

    <?php echo the_content(); ?>

    </div>          

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but that still hasn't sorted it. Still showing events on homepage that haven't the HOMEPAGE attribute.

Comment: If you want to chat I could send you the URL? Would rather not share a direct link on here.

Comment: Although I can't actually see how to create a chat, so could you?

Comment: @Kelvin I am on and off here at the moment, so chat probably not the best idea for me as it is quite live and I can't guarantee to be on here for more than 5 minutes at a time. If you can just edit the question with just the HTML I will take a look it, or if you feel it is too large you could put it somewhere like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and post a link to it.

Comment: Hmm... interesting, I'm actually surprised this outputs anything at all. Your code is looking for the string `<div id="homepage">yes</div>` which doesn't actually appear anywhere because the actual `<div>`s don't have the `yes` content. Where is the HTML inside the `<li>`s generated? Is it stored in a database?

Comment: I've no idea @DaveRandom. How would I find out? It's using Events Made Easy plugin.

Comment: This is in the plugin settings page. Marked as 'default event list format'; http://pastebin.com/G9VNePuS

Comment: Can you show the output of `var_dump($vReturn);`, if you add that on the line immediately before the `foreach`?